# space after using setDistributeEvently

Tags: java, android

I use these [SlidingTabLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java) and [SlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java) in my activity.

This is before I use setDistributeEvently

[image]

When I use setDistributeEvently it's add me space between Appbar and Fragment

[image]

Any solution ?